# Reapplying focus to a replaced DOM element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

In my app, lots of DOM elements using [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/). This is fine for the most part.

Occasionally, I have a form element that gets replaced whilst having focus. I want to be able to persist the focus for the user.

I have tried the following, but the problem is that jquery appears to consider the new node as exactly that and not an exact copy of the node it is replacing:

```
$(document).on('ajax:beforeSend',function(){
    window.focussed = $("*:focus");
});
$(document).on('ajax:complete',function(){
    window.focussed.focus();
});
```

Ideally, I would be able to achieve this without adding to the markup.

Comment: No idea what your HTML is so can't offer a complete solution but does the element being removed have a name or other attribute you can use to select it? You could store the _selector_ and use that to re-find the element with `$(selector).focus()`. Or alternatively use the index of the element being replaced to re-find it using [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: As mentioned, I would like to decouple this functionality from markup if I can

Comment: There would be no more coupling to the markup than what already exists. I was just asking if there was an alternative way to store a reference to the focused element, either via a DOM path or other attribute. If you add the HTML to the question, I might be able to suggest something more concrete

Answer (score 0):

If the element is being replaced by a new node, then focusing on the element saved in window.focussed won't do anything. If they have the same id, you could do this:

```
$(document).on('ajax:beforeSend',function(){
    window.focusedId = $("*:focus").prop("id");
});
$(document).on('ajax:complete',function(){
    $(window.focusedId).focus();
});
```

Comment: I wonder if there is another way to deduce a match from the information stored in `$("*:focus")` without requiring a specific attribute.